# Returning a value of callback function?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having some trouble with function callbacks, specifically with the HTML5 geolocation API. I'm a little new to Js as well. The function:

```
function getInfo()
{
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getPos);
}
```

takes a callback parameter of a function that gets the position passed into it.

```
function getPos(position)
{
PositionObj.lat = position.coords.latitude;
PositionObj.lon = position.coords.longitude;
}
```

I created a "location" object to store the coordinates, and I'm having trouble returning them.

```
var PositionObj = 
{
lat:null,
lon:null,
returnLat: function()
             {
             return this.lat;
             },
returnLon: function()
             {
             return this.lon;
             }
};


function printStuff()
{
getInfo();
console.log(PositionObj.returnLat());
}
```

EDIT: Syntax mistakes fixed. When I call printStuff(), I still get "null."

Comment: i dont see you returning anything from `getPos()`. Is it the problem?

Comment: I think you should try `getPos` (without `()`). You have to pass a function reference, not the return vzlue of the function getPos.

Answer (score 2):

- To pass the callback, use just `getPos` instead of calling the function right away.
- Use proper syntax to declare properties in `PositionObj`.

```
PositionObj = {
    lat: null,
    lon: null,
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I think this was the first thing I did wrong, can you please check my edit and see if there's something else that might be wrong with it? It seems as though it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Your `PositionObj` literal is incorrect. the initial properties should be set with colons:

```
{ lat: '', lon: '' }
```

Answer (score 1):

The callback should tell you that the request to get position information is asynchronous. This means that `getInfo()` does NOT set the values instantly, and therefore the following line cannot access the "new" values.

Anything that relies on the result of an asynchronous function MUST be within the callback itself.

Comment: Thanks, can you please give an example? Is there a resource where I can learn about asynchronous and synchronous functions in Js?